# Does Ranger Monster Hunter's Slayer's Counter works on saves to maintain concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger

From the Sage Advice Compendium:

> **Does a Monster Slayer ranger’s Supernatural Defense
> feature apply if a creature damages the ranger, thus
> causing the ranger to make a Constitution saving throw
> to maintain concentration on a spell?** Yes.

Since the Supernatural defense works for concentration, does the Slayer Counters works as well?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

The condition for making the reaction attack from Slayer's Counter is

> If the target of your Slayer’s Prey forces you to make a saving throw

and the target forcing you to make a saving throw to maintain your concentration falls under that. The SAC affirms this with the clarification that such a roll is valid for Monster Slayer's

> Whenever the target of your Slayer’s Prey forces you to make a saving throw

condition. So you'd both get to make an attack, and if it miss and you have to actually roll for concentration you can add a d6.